# rant error using ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

Executing one of the rant examples using ruby 1.9.3 in rant directory I get the following error:
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rant-0.5.7/doc/examples/directedrule

rant -T (reads the Rantfile that resides in the directory above)
String required as target directory

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think that rant is not compatible with ruby 1.9 syntax. please try it with 1.8.7.

Comment: I am aware that rant works well with 1.8.7 but I would like to migrate our code and rant scripts to 1.9.